# How do I get android location once at the push of a button?

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am currently making an application where I need to get the user's location when a button is clicked. I am using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates) sample and it works great as a sample application. My question is, how would I implement it into my application button's *onClick* event? I don't need it to refresh often, I just need it so that when the user clicks the button, it gets the user's latitude and longitude and saves them to two variables. What would be the best way to do this? I didn't post my own code because all I have is a button with an *onClick* event.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get the location on button click:

Implement `LocationListener` in your activity like:

```
   public class MainActivity Extends AppCompactActivity implements LocationListener
```

Then create an Instance For `LocationManager`, `longitude`, and `latitude` as below:

```
     LocationManager locationManager; // create global outside all methods
     Double currentLattitude, currentLongitude;
```

Set click event on your button as below:

```
      btnLocation.setOnClickListner( new View.onClickListner
      {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View v)
            {
                  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            }
      });
```

Now implement method for `LocationListener` as below:

```
       @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

           currentLattitude = location.getLatitude();
           currentLongitude = location.getLongitude());
       }

       @Override
       public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
             Log.d("Latitude","disable");
       }

       @Override
       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              Log.d("Latitude","enable");
       }

       @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
               Log.d("Latitude","status");
        }
```

With this, you can get your location via on click of your button.

Main thing to **don't forget** is to set permission (in your Manifest) as below:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***fused location API*** this is the fastest from all others.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

        btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                updateUI();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                    "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }
}
```

> - LocationListener provides call back for location change through onLocationChanged.
> - GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks provides call back for GoogleApiClient onConnected.
> - GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener provides call back for GoogleApiClient onConnectionFailed.

***Source:***  http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/

Comment: How would I call this from my MainActivity to get location when my button is clicked?

Comment: Check out the Link carefully you will get to know how to use it. Also it is called on button click on in it. Just implement these methods in your mainActivity  ` public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

Comment: Would this still be the best way to do it if I plan on using this on multiple activities?

Comment: yup it is the best way for more info read it Google developers blog

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I will try this now! :)

Comment: Your Welcome if it results helpful for you do not forget to accept the answer and upvote it :) Happy coding

Comment: I won't forget! :) Thanks again!